# Spring security. How to log out user (revoke oauth2 token)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

When I want to get logout I invoke this code:

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
```

But after it (in next request using old oauth token) I invoke

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`

and I see my old user there.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 43):

Here's my implementation (Spring OAuth2):

```
@Controller
public class OAuthController {
    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/revoke-token", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authHeader != null) {
            String tokenValue = authHeader.replace("Bearer", "").trim();
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
            tokenStore.removeAccessToken(accessToken);
        }
    }
}
```

For testing:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" http://localhost:8080/backend/oauth/revoke-token
```

Comment: If you don't want to remove access token (remember you can always change the query!) you may want to user DefaultServices (if you're using it)

Comment: You can directly use ConsumerTokenServices's revoke functions

Comment: I am trying to implement your suggestion in a github sample app.  Are you willing to take a look?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683434/how-to-autowire-this-tokenstore

Comment: @Ming, I'm revoking access token using `ConsumerTokenServices` on logout, but the next login attempt directly taking me to OAuth Approval page  instead of full authentication. Is it necessary to remove token from browser also?

Comment: Instead of `HttpServletRequest` as parameter, you can use `@RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String authHeader` directly

Comment: This is how it should be done, but it will not work with the `JwtTokenStore`. If you wish to remove a JWT refresh token, the `TokenStore.removeRefreshToken()` should be used instead and set the access token expiry to very short to mimic a token revocation behavior.

Comment: I'm able to logout with 200 response. But suppose token flush, when i try to access some API using postman with that token it allow me to do that.

Comment: Keep in mind if using JwtTokenStore then its't not actual store, it never stores anything... also `removeAccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken token)`  has empty body implementation for JwtTokenStore.

Answer (score 12):

The response by [camposer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3090309/camposer) can be improved using the API provided by Spring OAuth. In fact, it's not necessary to access directly to the HTTP headers, but the REST method which removes the access token can be implemented as follows:

```
@Autowired
private AuthorizationServerTokenServices authorizationServerTokenServices;

@Autowired
private ConsumerTokenServices consumerTokenServices;

@RequestMapping("/uaa/logout")
public void logout(Principal principal, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) principal;
    OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authorizationServerTokenServices.getAccessToken(oAuth2Authentication);
    consumerTokenServices.revokeToken(accessToken.getValue());

    String redirectUrl = getLocalContextPathUrl(request)+"/logout?myRedirect="+getRefererUrl(request);
    log.debug("Redirect URL: {}",redirectUrl);

    response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);

    return;
}
```

I also added a redirect to the endpoint of Spring Security logout filter, so the session is invalidated and the client must provide credentials again in order to access to the /oauth/authorize endpoint.

Comment: I tried same thing it return 200 response, but still i'm able to use same token and access the data.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on type of oauth2 'grant type' that you're using.

The most common if your have used spring's `@EnableOAuth2Sso` in your client app  is 'Authorization Code'. In this case Spring security redirects login request to the 'Authorization Server' and creates a session in your client app with the data received from 'Authorization Server'.

You can easy destroy your session at the client app calling `/logout` endpoint, but then client app sends user again to 'authorization server' and returns logged again.

I propose to create a mechanism to intercept logout request at client app and from this server code, call "authorization server" to invalidate the token.

The first change that we need is create one endpoint at the authorization server, using the code proposed by [Claudio Tasso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3350164/claudio-tasso), to invalidate the user's access_token.

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
public class InvalidateTokenController {


    @Autowired
    private ConsumerTokenServices consumerTokenServices;


    @RequestMapping(value="/invalidateToken", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, String> logout(@RequestParam(name = "access_token") String accessToken) {
        LOGGER.debug("Invalidating token {}", accessToken);
        consumerTokenServices.revokeToken(accessToken);
        Map<String, String> ret = new HashMap<>();
        ret.put("access_token", accessToken);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Then at the client app, create a `LogoutHandler`:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@Qualifier("mySsoLogoutHandler")
public class MySsoLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandler {

    @Value("${my.oauth.server.schema}://${my.oauth.server.host}:${my.oauth.server.port}/oauth2AuthorizationServer/invalidateToken")
    String logoutUrl;

    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) {

        LOGGER.debug("executing MySsoLogoutHandler.logout");
        Object details = authentication.getDetails();
        if (details.getClass().isAssignableFrom(OAuth2AuthenticationDetails.class)) {

            String accessToken = ((OAuth2AuthenticationDetails)details).getTokenValue();
            LOGGER.debug("token: {}",accessToken);

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            params.add("access_token", accessToken);

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("Authorization", "bearer " + accessToken);

            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity(params, headers);

            HttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
            HttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverternew = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
            restTemplate.setMessageConverters(Arrays.asList(new HttpMessageConverter[]{formHttpMessageConverter, stringHttpMessageConverternew}));
            try {
                ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(logoutUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
            } catch(HttpClientErrorException e) {
                LOGGER.error("HttpClientErrorException invalidating token with SSO authorization server. response.status code: {}, server URL: {}", e.getStatusCode(), logoutUrl);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

And register it at `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Autowired
MySsoLogoutHandler mySsoLogoutHandler;

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            // using this antmatcher allows /logout from GET without csrf as indicated in
            // https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-logout
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            // this LogoutHandler invalidate user token from SSO
            .addLogoutHandler(mySsoLogoutHandler)
    .and()
            ...
    // @formatter:on
}
```

One note: If you're using JWT web tokens, you can't invalidate it, because the token is not managed by the authorization server.

Comment: In case of JWT, yes you are right. Do you know a way to configure the auth server not to create session at all ( it uses session to store oauth client credential during the 'oauth dance' ) and use request param instead.

Answer (score 3):

Its up to your Token Store Implementation.

If you use **JDBC** token store then you just need to remove it from table...
Anyway you must add /logout endpoint manually then call this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logmeout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void logmeout(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String token = request.getHeader("bearer ");
    if (token != null && token.startsWith("authorization")) {

        OAuth2AccessToken oAuth2AccessToken = okenStore.readAccessToken(token.split(" ")[1]);

        if (oAuth2AccessToken != null) {
            tokenStore.removeAccessToken(oAuth2AccessToken);
        }
}
```

Comment: I am using JDBC token store, can you guide that how can I get tokenStore for last line "tokenStore.removeAccessToken(oAuth2AccessToken);" ?

Comment: @ChiragShah As I remember I couldn't reach my goal by this approach, please trace current error the see the correct implementation:(No matter whats your token store type) https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/issues/121

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between ```tokenStore.removeAccessToken``` and ```defaultTokenServices.revokeToken```?

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically you can log out this way:

```
public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      if (auth != null){    
         new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
      }
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in `<http></http>` tag.

```
<logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
```

This will delete JSESSIONID and invalidate session. And link to logout button or label would be something like:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout">Logout</a>
```

EDIT:
You want to invalidate session from java code. I assume you have to do some task right before logging the user out, and then invalidate session. If this is the use case, you should use custome logout handlers. Visit [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-logout) site for more information.

Comment: Why are you doing it from Java code? Any specific use case?

Comment: Yes. specific use case.

Comment: See the edit. I guess you have to do something before logout process. You can write logout handlers to do such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

This works for Keycloak Confidential Client logout.  I have no idea why the folks over at keycloak don't have more robust docs on java non-web clients and their endpoints in general, I guess that's the nature of the beast with open source libs.  I had to spend a bit of time in their code:

```
    //requires a Keycloak Client to be setup with Access Type of Confidential, then using the client secret
public void executeLogout(String url){

    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    //not required but recommended for all components as this will help w/t'shooting and logging
    requestHeaders.set( "User-Agent", "Keycloak Thick Client Test App Using Spring Security OAuth2 Framework");
    //not required by undertow, but might be for tomcat, always set this header!
    requestHeaders.set( "Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );

    //the keycloak logout endpoint uses standard OAuth2 Basic Authentication that inclues the
    //Base64-encoded keycloak Client ID and keycloak Client Secret as the value for the Authorization header
     createBasicAuthHeaders(requestHeaders);

    //we need the keycloak refresh token in the body of the request, it can be had from the access token we got when we logged in:
    MultiValueMap<String, String> postParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    postParams.set( OAuth2Constants.REFRESH_TOKEN, accessToken.getRefreshToken().getValue() );

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(postParams, requestHeaders);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    try {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        System.out.println("We should get a 204 No Content - did we?\n" + e.getMessage());          
    }
} 

//has a hard-coded client ID and secret, adjust accordingly
void createBasicAuthHeaders(HttpHeaders requestHeaders){
     String auth = keycloakClientId + ":" + keycloakClientSecret;
     byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(
        auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")) );
     String authHeaderValue = "Basic " + new String( encodedAuth );
     requestHeaders.set( "Authorization", authHeaderValue );
}
```

Comment: FYI:  this was tested on Keylcoak 2.4.0 FINAL.

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by user **composer** perfectly worked for me. I made some minor changes to the code as follows,

```
@Controller
public class RevokeTokenController {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/revoke-token", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authHeader != null) {
            try {
                String tokenValue = authHeader.replace("Bearer", "").trim();
                OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
                tokenStore.removeAccessToken(accessToken);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return new ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }           
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I did this because If you try to invalidate same access token again, it throws Null Pointer exception.

Comment: I tried same thing it return 200 response, but still i'm able to use the same token and access the data.

Answer (score 0):

At AuthServer

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
    throws Exception {
  ...
  endpoints.addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptorAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
      if (modelAndView != null
          && modelAndView.getView() instanceof RedirectView) {
        RedirectView redirect = (RedirectView) modelAndView.getView();
        String url = redirect.getUrl();
        if (url.contains("code=") || url.contains("error=")) {
          HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
          if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

At client site

```
.and()
.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
.and().csrf()
.ignoringAntMatchers("/login", "/logout")
.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
```

Seems a better solutions for me. referred this [link](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_oauth2_logout_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_ix)

Answer (score 0):

for logout token with spring boot rest security and oauth2.0
user as follow

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.ConsumerTokenServices;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/user/")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private ConsumerTokenServices consumerTokenServices;

    /**
     * Logout. This method is responsible for logout user from application based on
     * given accessToken.
     * 
     * @param accessToken the access token
     * @return the response entity
     */
    @GetMapping(value = "/oauth/logout")
    public ResponseEntity<Response> logout(@RequestParam(name = "access_token") String accessToken) {
        consumerTokenServices.revokeToken(accessToken);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new Response(messageSource.getMessage("server.message.oauth.logout.successMessage",  null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())), HttpStatus.OK);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can remove both access token and refresh token from database to save the space.**

```
    @PostMapping("/oauth/logout")
public ResponseEntity<String> revoke(HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        String authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authorization != null && authorization.contains("Bearer")) {
            String tokenValue = authorization.replace("Bearer", "").trim();

            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
            tokenStore.removeAccessToken(accessToken);

            //OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = tokenStore.readRefreshToken(tokenValue);
            OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = accessToken.getRefreshToken();
            tokenStore.removeRefreshToken(refreshToken);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Invalid access token");
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Access token invalidated successfully");
}
```