# How to autowire this TokenStore

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, autowired, spring-oauth2

**How do I trigger auto-logout of [this sample Spring Boot OAuth2 app](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2)?**

I tried adding the following code from [an answer to this other posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987589/spring-security-how-to-log-out-user-revoke-oauth2-token#32320860) into a new controller class in the `demo` package of the [`authserver` app](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2/authserver):

```
package demo;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

@Controller
public class OAuthController {
    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/revoke-token", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authHeader != null) {
            String tokenValue = authHeader.replace("Bearer", "").trim();
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
            tokenStore.removeAccessToken(accessToken);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to launch the app, the debug log gives the following error indicating that it cannot `autowire` the token store:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  
Could not autowire field:  
private org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore  
demo.OAuthController.tokenStore; nested exception is  
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:  
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:  
No qualifying bean of type  
[org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore]  
found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as  
autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:  
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545        )
    ... 25 more
```

When the compilation error is resolved, I intend to trigger the logout process from the following code which will be added to the [`hello.js` controller of the `ui` app](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/ui/src/main/resources/static/js/hello.js) in the github link above:

```
self.logout = function() {
    $http.post('http://localhost:9000/oauth/revoke-token', {}).finally(function() {
        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        $location.path("/");
    });
}
```

**The full code of the sample app is at the github link above, so what specific changes do I need to make in order to successfully `autowire` the `token store` and auto-logout the user globally?**

---

**ONGOING EFFORTS:**

---

Per @ManoJ's suggestion, I changed the new controller class to become the following:

```
package demo;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

@Controller
public class OAuthController {

    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    public OAuthController(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/revoke-token", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authHeader != null) {
            String tokenValue = authHeader.replace("Bearer", "").trim();
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
            tokenStore.removeAccessToken(accessToken);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am still getting a very similar error message when I try to launch the app at the terminal with `mvn spring-boot:run`, as follows:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuthController' defined in file [/home/user/spring_boot_apps/security_tut_remodel/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/oauth2/authserver/target/classes/demo/OAuthController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore]: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at demo.AuthserverApplication.main(AuthserverApplication.java:88)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 25 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Given that this class is the only addition to the sample app in the link in the first line of the `OP` above, all of the code for the entire app is available both online and on your own devbox with `git clone ...`.  So what else needs to change in order for autowire of the TokenStore to work properly?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error is quite clear, it means, that you don't have a bean of type `TokenStore` defined. The default configuration of Spring Security OAuth doesn't expose the token store as a bean, so you have to do it by yourself:

```
@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new InMemoryTokenStore();
}
```

Use the appropriate implementation here (can also be JwtTokenStore or RedisTokenStore or your own).

Then create a configuration class which extends `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`, where you configure that token store for Spring Security OAuth, so that it doesn't create a default one again:

```
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to inject that TokenStore bean wherever you want.

Comment: Thank you and +1. I marked this as accepted because you answered the question. However, to avoid overposting clutter, can you please also show how to use tokenStore in a **DIFFERENT** controller after you autowire it? For example, the following code from the OP throws a compilation error asking what `tokenStore` is unless I put it inside your `AuthorizationServerConfiguration` class: `@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/revoke-token", method = RequestMethod.GET) @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK) public void logout(HttpServletRequest request) { ...  tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);...}`

Comment: If you use it how you did it in your OAuthController, it should be fine. Of course you have to define the field `tokenStore` if you want to use it (and autowire the field or the constructor).

Comment: @dunni Thank you so much. you save my day :)

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing similar issue in my project. I changed the @autowired annotation to constructor dependency. you can try below code.

```
private TokenStore tokenStore;

@Autowired
public OAuthController(TokenStore tokenStore) {
    this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
}
```

Comment: Thank you and +1 for looking into this problem.  However, your suggestion left an error until the other user's suggested code was added to successfully inject the `@Bean`.